# how to hide the element in template based on another field's value - kendoui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a column as below.

```
var commentsTemplate = "<input class='comments-button' type='image' src='images/comments_button.png'/>#: COMMENTS #";

{ "field": "COMMENTS", "title": "Comments", "template": matcher_comments_template},
{ "field": "TYPE", "title": "Type"},
```

I want the input element dynamically show and hide based on the TYPE field's value. For example, if type is Good, hide the button, if type is Not Good, show the button. Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow):

```
var commentsTemplate = "<input class='comments-button' type='image' src='images/comments_button.png' ng-show="{{currentValue.title == "Good"}}"/>#: COMMENTS #";
```

Assuming currentValue is a parent object where your main javascript object (`{ "field": "TYPE", "title": "Type"},`) is stored.

### Edit 1

OP asked for an implementation without bindings of his variables.
What can i think it's a "homemade watcher" in the controller:

```
<input class='comments-button' type='image' src='images/comments_button.png' ng-show="shouldShowMe()"/>
```

and, in the controller:

```
$scope.shouldShowMe = function(){
  return title == "Good";
}
```

Comment: If there's no ng-model binded, any other ways? thanks

Comment: A directive that does that for you. i'll edit my post to show you an example

Comment: My apologies, but i don't think it's possible without referencig to AT LEAST your controller, or using jquery. it's ok to you to reference to your controller or add jquery as dependency?